# How do I pass the function argument in arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, bit-manipulation, arduino-c++

I'm trying to control velocity in a motor via writing register value in microcontroller.

```
unsigned long PrintHex32( uint32_t data) // prints 32-bit data in hex with leading zeroes
{
  uint32_t data2 = data << 8;
  char tmp[16];
  uint16_t LSB = data2 & 0xffff;
  uint16_t MSB = data2 >> 16;
  unsigned long ppsval2 = sprintf(tmp, "0x%.4X%.4X%", MSB, LSB);
  Serial.println(tmp);
  Serial.println("***************");
  return tmp;
}
void NoRamp() {
  Serial.println("No Ramp");
  unsigned long ppsVal = (VMAX * FS * uS);
  unsigned long   ppsVal3 = PrintHex32(ppsVal);
  Serial.println(ppsVal);
  Serial.println(ppsVal3);
  Serial.println("$$$$$$");

  //********* NO Ramp **********////////
  sendData(0xA0, 0x00000000); //RAMP Mode
  //  sendData(0xA4, 0x03E80000); //VMAX-5rps/5hz
  //  sendData(0xA4, 0x00c80000);
  sendData(0xA4, ppsVal3); //VMAX-1rps/1hz

}
```

at the end i need to be send data format after hex conversion **sendData(0xA4, 0x00c80000)**

but currently, I'm getting my print output:

```
No Ramp
0x00C80000
***************
51200
0
$$$$$$
```

umm where do I making the mistake? Can anyone kindly slam my head a bit please!
 Thanks heaps!!

PS: also senddata method take below argument if anyone needs to know!

```
unsigned long sendData(unsigned long address, unsigned long datagram)
```

**Edit:**
I think I can understand the proper question to ask?

```
unsigned long PrintHex32( uint32_t data) // prints 32-bit data in hex with leading zeroes
{
  uint32_t data2 = data << 8;
  //char tmp[16];
  uint16_t LSB = data2 & 0xffff;
  uint16_t MSB = data2 >> 16;
   unsigned long  val = xxxx(uint16_t LSB) + uint16_t MSB(YYY);
  //sprintf(tmp, "0x%.4X%.4X%", MSB, LSB);
  return val ;
}
```

if you can see im converting my input data2 to hex using **uint16_t LSB** and **uint16_t MSB**. how do i save that two value as one single **unsigned  long val** . then I can return the that varible.
I think using sprintf method is wrong as it does show just char representation?
please kindly correct me this if im wrong?

Comment: it is already long. "unsigned long sendData(unsigned long address, unsigned long datagram)" if you are ref to send data method

Comment: `PrintHex32` has return type `unsigned long` but `return tmp;` tries to return a `char[16]` - that shouldn't even compile.

Comment: You're calling as sendData(0xA4, 0x00c80000) , first parameter is address and second is data,  so the function prototype should be `unsigned long sendData( unsigned long* address, unsigned long data);`

Comment: could you pls check the new edit pls!

Answer (score 0):

The xxxx in the edit should probably be 2^16 aka 65536:

```
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

unsigned int data2 = 12345678;
uint16_t LSB = data2 & 0xffff;
uint16_t MSB = data2 >> 16;
unsigned long  val = (1<<16) * MSB + LSB;
unsigned long  val2 = 65536 * MSB + LSB;
assert(val == data2);
assert(val2 == data2);
}
```